# Total Gym To Get A Ripped Body

Tags: exercise, strength, exercise-technique

I' m busy with my work routine and I don't have time to go to a Gym. But I want to have a ripped body. So I m thinking to buy a Total Gym product. I have seen it have no effect like a real GYM. But I don't want to be a body builder so Will it be a good exercise equipment for men ?

Answer (score 3):

None of the exercise you do or the equipment you use matters for acquiring a "ripped" body. A ripped body is just a body that has a low percentage of body fat. You can be ripped but still be emaciated or malnourished. Of course, I am just illustrating a point to make my initial claim more clear. If you wish to lose weight you can do so by creating a caloric deficit through your diet. This means weighing foods and counting calories.

Of course doing so through diet alone will take a long time and if you're overweight will result in loose skin so typically what people do is they combine a diet with exercise. What exercise doesn't really matter but studies show that low to regular intensity cardio doesn't aid as much to the efforts as resistance training or high intensity interval training(HIIT) do.

If you're overweight you should combine a caloric deficit with resistance training. If you have a normal BMI and aren't carrying anything like a belly or love handles and have a "normal" yet undefined composition and just want to get ripped you would probably benefit more from cardio.

**One important thing: you can't outrun a bad diet.**

Comment: "You can't outrun a bad diet" - Bollocks to that. You just haven't run far enough. A decent paced half-marathon burns about 1500 Calories. That's just for the run, not recover and is on top of your TDEE.

Comment: Maybe in the case of an athlete who is already conditioned and fit, but, respectfully you're making an extreme case relative to OP's original question.

Comment: 1500 calories is less than 3 big macs: http://caloriecount.about.com/calories-big-mac-i21111

Comment: I don't think you will manage to outrun a bad diet by running marathons, unless you can run a marathon a day. It depends of how bad your diet is.